# Are line breaks possible in Python match case patterns?

Tags: python, match, code-formatting

I want a `match` pattern with a rather long OR-pattern something like:

```
match item:
   case Really.Long.Qualified.Name.ONE | Really.Long.Qualified.Name.TWO | Really.Long.Qualified.Name.THREE | Some.Other.Patterns.Here:
      pass
```

This is obviously very annoying to have on a single line.   However, PyCharm doesn't seem to warn about longline as per usual and reports syntax errors if I use a line-break (even if it's escaped).

Is there any way to format this code more nicely, or must the entire pattern be on a single line?  Is there a definitive source that establishes this - I couldn't find it in the PEP for match/case OR in particular.

If the latter, why would that language design decision be made?  It seems... not good....

Comment: (Yes, I know about 'in' case patterns, they're not what I want and I'm asking exactly the question above...)

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap such chain expressions within a pair of parenthesis.

```py
match item:
   case (
      Really.Long.Qualified.Name.ONE |
      Really.Long.Qualified.Name.TWO |
      Really.Long.Qualified.Name.THREE |
      Some.Other.Patterns.Here
   ):
      pass
```